# Swift change constraint values in viewdidload

Tags: swift, constraints

I have a `tableView` that containts a image in each cell. When the app starts I check if the user is using a iphone 5 or iphone 6 plus then I change the cell height and image height constraint to fit the device.

Right now I change the height constraint inside `viewDidLoad` but is this the right place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to use a tableView function:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return [DESIRED HEIGHT]
}
```

This way you can create conditions for each type of cell and set their height here.

The image constraints should be related to the cell's bounds.

Comment: I will test it. Right now I am using this in viewDidLoad:
`self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 120`
`self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`